# How to ssh into Kubernete Pod

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, ssh, kubectl

Scenario 1: I am deploying an spring boot app in a physical machine in which it opens ssh connection on a port of the physical machine. Lets say 9889. So once the application starts, that physical machine will open connection on that port and listen for any incoming request. Any  client can connect to that port using command

```
ssh admin@ipaddress -p 9889.
```

It returns the connection i expect.

Scenario 2: I am deploying that app into Kubernete cluster. I set external Ip of the service to the IP on master node. So when i type Kubectl get services i got something like

```
NAME           TYPE                 CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP          PORT
app-entry      LOADBALANCER         172.x.x.xx     172.x.x.x            3000:3552
```

How can i ssh to the app in the Kubernete Cluster using the externalIP and the port 3000. Since everytime i try to ssh using command above it returns connection refused

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/get-shell-running-container/

Comment: Is the Spring application running an ssh server itself; if you run it with `java -jar` can you ssh into it?  Or is it running an ordinary TCP or HTTP service, and you're just connecting to it over an ssh tunnel?  Where does ssh fit into the final Kubernetes setup?

Comment: Yes i can ssh into the spring app itself. The problem is inside the main method i open ssh connection for listening request on ANOTHER PORT OF THE SAME  MACHINE. So lests say the spring runs on port 9000, inside the main method it opens the port 9889. THe library I use is Apache Mina sshd.

Answer (score 2):

As @zerkms mentioned in the comment, you can use `kubectl exec` to connect the shell of a container running inside the Kubernetes cluster.

```sh
$ kubectl exec -it -n <namespace> <pod_name> -- /bin/bash
$ kubectl exec -it -n <namespace> <pod_name> -- /bin/sh

# if the pod has multiple containers
$ kubectl exec -it -n <namespace> <pod_name> -c <container_name> -- /bin/bash
```

If you have a running server on your pod which serves at a specific port,  you can use `kubectl port-forward` to connect it from the local machine (ie. `localhost:PORT`).

```
# Pods
$ kubectl port-forward -n <namespace> pods/<pod_name> <local_port>:<container_port>

# Services
$ kubectl port-forward -n <namespace> svc/<service_name> <local_port>:<container_port>
```

Comment: The problem is that it seems i don't have openssh server running inside my Docker container and i need to install it.